# Has any one out there in the field used Dispatcher.Yield?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

In "[Lucian Wischik - Async Part 2 -- deep dive into the new language feature of VB/C#](http://vimeo.com/43808833)" for NDC 2012, the recommended use of `Dispatcher.Yield` is introduced to me. Does anyone out there have examples (and explanations) of how (and why) this call is used in the wild?

Answer (score 4):

Well for example if you have a long running task but you still need to update your UI you can use `Yield`.

`Yield` gives you the ability to leave the current thread context and allow other code to run in the underlying context.

```
public async void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for( int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ProcessSomeStuff(i);

        // await the Yield to ensure all waiting messages
        // are processed before continuing
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

In the example above you can process stuff async but calling `Yield` will allow events on the UI thread to execute also,

Answer (score 0):

I love to use "await Dispatcher.Yield()" whenever I develop WPF applications.
It is easy to use and barely makes any problems in most cases.

The most useful case using Dispatcher.Yield() is when there is a small time of lag in a operation, which can not be bypassed by "Task", "Thread" etc.

For example, let's say that there is a command button which opens a new window or tab.

```
    private void aButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do some ui stuff
    // You can not use Task here at large.
}
```

What happens here is the whole application stopping, and the button UI remains pressed until the new window or tab opens. It is bad user experience and makes the apllicaiton seem so much slow.

and here is a code with a trick.

```
    private async void aButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.Yield();

    // Do some ui stuff
}
```

In here, your code works differently. Dispathcer will process other ui operations first before getting into the job. The button pressed motion will be released first and then a new window will come.

Application stopping will be same, but to users the application will be much smooth and fast. So it is usually a good idea to adopt Dispatcher.Yield() in your application.

In addition, Task.Yield() is different from Dispatcher.Yield(). Try two options and see the results.